Export Microsoft's building footprint as shapefile for a specific region
I am trying to export Microsoft's building footprint for a specific region as shapefile. I am using the code below:
var feature = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/sat-io/open-datasets/MSBuildings/United_Kingdom')
.filterBounds(table);

var london = feature.filterBounds(table)

//export parameters
var exportParams = {
  collection: london,
  description: 'United_Kingdom_Buildings',
  folder: 'GEE_exports',
  fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'
};

Export.table.toDrive(exportParams);

Alhough it seems that the code works fine, I am guessing it exports the building footprints for the entire planet and not just for the the region I specified (London). I am saying this because it runs for over an hour and a half so far.
Is this the right way to clip a FeatureCollection?
The code and the shp I'm using.
